# Scrolling a UIScrollView regardless of where the touch occurs

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, tableview, scrollview

The end goal is to create the same scrolling effect as the one on the "Me" tab of the twitter iOS app where the segmented control rises to the top as you scroll down and then stays fixed to it unless scrolled back up to the top.

The solution I've come up with is illustrated below.  There is a view at the top, a segmented control, and a table view beneath the segmented control.  All of these elements are embedded inside a scrollview that takes up the entire screen (minus tab & nav bars).

Here is the key issue: If begin scrolling by swiping up from the top-most view or the segmented control, it scrolls the scrollview that all the elements are embedded in.  If I scroll the tableview, it will only scroll itself and leave the top-most view and segmented control unaffected.

How can I scroll the scrollview that the elements are embedded in no matter where the scrolling occurs on screen?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar layout in one of my projects. I used [SJSegmentedViewController](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/sjsegmentedviewcontroller).

It Requires a headerViewController ,datasource for middle segment and viewController array for those segments.

This library allows you to scroll from anywhere on the screen moreover the segmented control sticks to the top as user scrolls all the way to top.

Here is how you can implement this :

First import the module into your class

```
import SJSegmentedScrollView
```

Then create a headerViewController and two viewControllers(Say Video and Tips) for segment

```
let headerViewController = HeaderViewController()
let video = VideoController()
let tips = TipsController()
```

After that set these Controller and also set the title for segmented control as following:

```
segmentController.headerViewController = header
segmentController.segmentControllers = [video,tips]
video.title = "Video"
tips.title = "Tips"
```

Then add it to the Container View

```
addChildViewController(segmentController)
containerView.addSubview(segmentController.view)
segmentController.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds
segmentController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

Here Container View is a **UIContainerView**

Last but make sure to call in child controllers (VideoController,TipsController), After calling this function in those controllers you can scroll from anywhere on the screen.

```
extension HomeListingViewController: SJSegmentedViewControllerViewSource {

    func viewForSegmentControllerToObserveContentOffsetChange() -> UIView {
        //Scrollview in child controllers
        return scrollview 
    }
}
```

You can find the full documentation [here](https://github.com/subinspathilettu/SJSegmentedViewController)

Hope this helps!